# Loop analysis in confusing circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis

Here is the circuit I am trying to analyse.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhJevo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I know generally how to do this.

Loop 1 we can call the RIGHT one and Loop 2 we will call the LEFT one.

Loop 2 is clearly 2A because it has a current source.

Loop 1 is 30/10 = 3A

and the voltage at A is clearly 12V because V = 3A*4

But how in the world do I find the Node voltage at B?

Comment: Just follow the path from A to B. A = 12 V, across R3 we get  ? V because the current is ? A. Then subtract 5V of V1 then add the voltage across R1 (minding the direction of the current and thus the polarity of V(R1) ) then you're at B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is a trick question :'(

It sounds like you are an early student of electrical engineering and, as such, this question is a bit unfair.

The circuit you have drawn is essentially two *separate* devices and they are connected together by *only one wire*.

### The two devices are:

- RIGHT: R4, R5, V2
- LEFT: R1, R2, I1

You see, your reference point (the down-triangle or "Ground")  is on the right device (network) and the other device is floating (not referenced to "0 Volts" at any point).

### The analysis

The goal, then, is to determine the relationship of LEFT to ground. The key observation is that *no current can flow between LEFT and RIGHT at steady state*. There is only one wire between LEFT and RIGHT, so there is no return path for the current.

Therefore...

- You can solve for A using only R4, R5, and V2. It's a simple voltage-divider.
- The voltage at A is 5V higher than the voltage at the LEFT device's connection to V1 because there is no current in the connecting path, but a 5V drop due to V1.
- You can solve for the voltage V1(-) to B because you know R1's resistance and R1's current (must be the same everywhere in the loop = I1 = 2A).

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you!  and yes this is my first circuits class.